# Can we draw custom legends not based on series in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to draw custom legends. Actually number of series determine number of legends in highcharts. So is it possible to draw customized number of legends which are not dependent on number of series.
Suppose I have two series but I want to draw 10 legends and I want customized actions on click on each legend.

Answer (score 8):

Disable default legend and create your own by HTML. Further catch click event on items (by i.e jquery) and reconigse if this element should interact with chart. If yes, then call `chart.series[0].show/hide` where series[0] is index of available serie and manipulate view.

Docs:
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.show

Comment: Is there any example where legends are created by HTML.